# How do active class on pagination

Tags: php, mysql, css, pagination

I'm trying to active class on list

Kindly if any one can help me to add `class="active"` on displayed pagination page:

```
$perpage= $conf['perpage'];
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 
    $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
} else { 
    $page=1; 
}; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $perpage; 
$result = "SELECT * FROM topics LIMIT $start_from, $perpage"; 
$result = mysql_query ($result); 
$n = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['topic_no'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    ++$n;
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $perpage); 
echo '<ul class="pagination">'; 
echo "<li><a href='topics.php?page=1'>".'<'."</a></li> ";  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
    echo "<li  ><a href='topics.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li> "; 
}; 
echo "<li><a href='topics.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>'."</a> </li>"; 

echo '</ul> ';
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What problem are you having, specifically? Don't you just need to compare `$i` with `$_GET['page']`? (I recommend adding some indentation to this, both for your benefit and ours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  echo "<li if($_GET['page']==$i){ class='active'}><a href='topics.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li> ";
```

Please try this. It might help you

Answer (score 3):

```
$active = $i == $page ? 'class="active"' : '';
echo "<li  ><a {$active} href=\"topics.php?page={$i}\">{$i}</a></li> ";
```

We just need to add class="active" only if page is current, otherwise we add nothing. If you already have classes for rows - you just need to use smth like

```
$activeClass = $i == $page ? 'active' : '';
echo "<li  ><a class=\"my-row-class1 {$activeClass}\" href=\"topics.php?page={$i}\">{$i}</a></li> ";
```

Comment: Please ad details on how to implement your solution and what it does exactly so beginners feel safe to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You Can also try this code. it's working

```
    $c="active"; 
    for ($i=1; $i <$total_page ; $i++) {

    if($page==$i)
    {
        $c="active";
    }
    else
    {
        $c="";
    }
    echo "<li class=\"$c\"><a href=\"archive.php?page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = @$_GET['page'];  // get value form other page

$page ='A';

for ($Page=1; $Page <27 ; $Page++) {  ?>  // abcdef... create

<li class="<?php if($search==$page){ echo 'active'; } ?>"> <?php echo  '<a href="alphabetic-result.php?page='.$page.' ">'. $page++ . '</a>' ;?> </li>  

<?php } ?>

/* if($search==$page){ echo 'active'; } this code means if search value == alphabet then class active call automatically */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $isActive = isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $i ? "active" : "";
    echo "<li class='page-item $isActive'><a class='page-link' href='pagination.php?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
```

this will work for sure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).